# How to handle Many To Many relationship with three or more classes with Laravel and MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm working on a project with Laravel and Eloquent/MySQL.

I'd like to know how to handle a many-to-many relationship with three tables (users, merchants, roles).

- Any user can have one or more merchant.
- Any merchant can be shared between users.
- Any user have a specific role for a merchant.

Is there a best practice to follow?

How can I get all the merchants by a user having a specific role?

Thanks for helping

This is my current structure:

```
Users
-------------------------------
| id | first_name | last_name |
-------------------------------
```

```
Merchants
-------------------
| id | trade_name |
-------------------
```

```
Roles
-------------------------
| id | name | hierarchy |
-------------------------
```

```
merchant_user_role
-----------------------------------
| merchant_id | user_id | role_id |
-----------------------------------
```

Merchant Model

```php
<?php
class Merchant extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'merchant_user_role')
            ->withPivot('role_id')
            ->withTimestamps()
            ->orderBy('first_name', 'asc');
    }
}
```

User Model

```php
<?php

class User extends Model
{
    public function merchants()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Merchant', 'merchant_user_role')
            ->withPivot('role_id')
            ->withTimestamps()
            ->orderBy('trade_name', 'asc');
    }

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'merchant_user_role')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Role Model

```php
<?php

class Role extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$merchants = $user->merchants()->where('role_id', $some_role_id)->get();
```

Comment: Is there a way to use roles.hierarchy instead of role_id?

Comment: ```$merchants = Merchants::whereHas('users', function($query) use($user_id, $hierarchy ) {
    $query->where('user_id', $user_id)->whereHas('roles', function($query) use($hierarchy ) {
        $query->where('hierarchy', $hierarchy);
    });
})->get();```

Comment: I was trying `$this->user->merchants()->getAdmin()` but with no success
`
public function scopeGetAdmin($query)
{
        return $query->wherePivot('role_id', 1)->orderBy('trade_name', 'asc')->get());
}`
I got this error: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pivot' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from merchants inner join merchant_user_role on merchants.id = merchant_user_role.merchant_id where merchant_user_role.user_id = 164 and pivot = role order by trade_name asc, trade_name asc)`

Comment: Why doesn't work when I put the code in a local scoped method? `public function scopeGetAdmin($query) { return $query->withPivot('role_id')->wherePivot('role_id', 1); }` throws `BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::withPivot()`. I call that method with `$user->merchants()->getAdmin()`

Comment: withPivot method applies to belongsToMany, but not applied to eloquent query. merchants relation already contain withPivot. use $user->merchants()->where('role_id', $some_role_id)->get();